# Reactjs: How to ensure that the response from a POST request is not going to be modified by the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have the following code that makes a post request to my Nodejs app on the backend:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/ws', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}).then(res => { 
  return res.json(); 
}).then(data => { 
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Everything works fine, it sends the request and gets the response successfully. The problem is that most of the browsers allows the users to debug my code, they can put a breakpoint where the response is being handled and modify its values.

How can I prevent them from doing that?

Answer (score 6):

You can't apply that kind of control to code running on the client. You should always assume it's untrusted code running on the client. If you need controls, you'll have to apply them on the server.